# Adding a parameter to the flask unittest

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask, parameter-passing

I'm trying to unittest my app in flask, but I'm getting a little bit stuck witch this one. I want to add a parameter to my app route but I don't know how to do this. Can anybody help me?

I set the vacancy id hardcoded in the test for now, but I will add a connection and a query to the database. But I first wanted to get this to work

This is the route:

```
@app.route('/add_application/<vacancy_id>')
def add_application(vacancy_id):
   return render_template(
        'addapplication.html')
```

This is my test so far:

```
VACANCY_ID = '5f67bc3643f71774b981ebfc'

def test_addapplicationFromVacancy(self):
    tester = app.test_client(self)
    tester.post(
        '/login',
        data=dict(username=USERNAME_USER, password=SPW_TWO),
        follow_redirects=True
    )
    response = tester.get(
        '/add_application/',
        data={'vacancy_id': VACANCY_ID},
        content_type='html/text'
    )
    print()
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

Comment: Can you explain the result of running your test as is.. If it's throwing errors post the stacktrace in your question

Comment: I got a 500 error cause of the missing id paramater. The sollution of Grzegorz Redlicki worked perfectly!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know your whole application however I see at least two things which could help you here:

1. You shouldn't use `self` during creating the client because this is the object of the `unittest.TestCase` class, not the Flask application's one. And it will be passed automatically.

   ```py
   tester = app.test_client()
   ```
2. Your endpoint use the URL parameter, so the get request should look more or less like this:

   ```py
   tester.get(f"/add_application/{VACANCY_ID}", ...)
   ```

   **I have used here f-string, feel free to change it if you are not using >=3.6 version of Python*